# I am trying to make a C code based on a Flowchart, but I am having a trouble doing it

Tags: c

this is the flowchart I am trying to make
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCFHu.png

and this is my code look so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int AA = 5;
    char NA = 'K';

step2:
    if (NA == 'K')
    {
        printf("NA= %c" , NA);
        printf("AA= %d ", AA);
    }
    else if (AA < 3)
    {
        (NA = 'B');
        printf("NA= %c", NA); 
        printf("AA= %d", AA);
    }
    else if (AA < 4)
    {
     (NA = 'C');
        printf("NA= %c", NA);
        printf("AA= %d", AA);
    }

        else
        {
        printf("input value of NA =");
            scanf("%c", &NA);
        printf("input value of AA =");
            scanf("%d", &AA);
        };
        goto step2;

    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to make the code after step 6 is false revert back to step 2 until the conditional turns out true help me out here friend!

Comment: First step is to remove `goto`. If you have to use `goto` you have lost the battle already. `goto` should rarely be used and certainly not when you are just learning the language. I'm pretty sure the exercise wants you to use a real looping construct such as `while`.

Comment: I don't know how to use while , to be exact I don't know where to put it in the code

Comment: You may find it useful to try drawing out the flowchart for your code and comparing it to the provided flowchart

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely use a loop :

```
// 1 : initialise na and aa 
// 2 : loop while na is not K
while (na != ´K’) {
    // 5 : Check aa
   If (aa < 3) {
       // 7
       // 10
   } else {
       // 4 : test
       If () {
           // 8
           // 9
        } else {
        // 6 : test aa
        … continue with the others test/print statements 
        }
   }
}
// 3 : print aa,na
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to write my own solution to this problem, I hope it will help you:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char na = 'X';
    int aa = 5;

    if (na == 'K') {
        printf("aa = %d\nna = %c", aa, na);
        return 0;
    }

    if (aa < 3) {
        na = 'B';
        printf("aa = %d\nna = %c", aa, na);
        return 0;
    }

    if (aa < 4) {
        na = 'C';
        printf("aa = %d\nna = %c", aa, na);
        return 0;
    }

    /* input */
    printf("aa = ");
    scanf("%d", &aa);
    printf("na = ");
    scanf("%u", &na);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is not doing what the flowchart defines. There is clearly a loop missing.

Comment: Outputs deserve a `"\n"`.